# I am unable to configure reactjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I am new to reactjs . when i trid to install new reactjs app it shows following error.

Prathamesh@PRATHAMESH MINGW64 ~/Desktop/reactForm
$ npx create-react-app form

Creating a new React app in C:\Users\Prathamesh\Desktop\reactForm\form.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...//registry.npmjs.org/'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Prathamesh\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-03-30T19_34_56_684Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting form/ from C:\Users\Prathamesh\Desktop\reactForm
Done.

Comment: Can you post the package.json code please?

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the NPM cache and try again.

```
npm cache clean --force
```